# Convert string[] to int[] in one line of code using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have an array of integers in string form:

```
var arr = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

I need to an array of 'real' integers to push it further:

```
void Foo(int[] arr) { .. }
```

I tried to cast int and it of course failed:

```
Foo(arr.Cast<int>.ToArray());
```

I can do next:

```
var list = new List<int>(arr.Length);
arr.ForEach(i => list.Add(Int32.Parse(i))); // maybe Convert.ToInt32() is better?
Foo(list.ToArray());
```

or

```
var list = new List<int>(arr.Length);
arr.ForEach(i =>
{
   int j;
   if (Int32.TryParse(i, out j)) // TryParse is faster, yeah
   {
      list.Add(j);
   }
 }
 Foo(list.ToArray());
```

but both looks ugly.

Is there any other ways to complete the task?

Comment: What's wrong with simply iterating through one collection, converting the value, and the adding it to the second?  Seems pretty clear in intention to me.

Comment: Otherwise, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx

Comment: Just FYI, I'm using this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297325/can-i-compare-il-code-to-determine-which-technique-is-faster-or-better

Comment: Related: [convert string-array to int-array, fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083529/convert-string-to-int/3083567#3083567)

Comment: TryParse is not faster (except if your strings are invalid, but in that case you *want* the exception to alert you).

Comment: I'm a little curious why my answer was unaccepted after ~3 years. In any case I added a LINQ solution just to satisfy the original question, which was very similar to the `ConvertAll` approach.

Comment: @AhmadMageed: o_O Oops, indeed, sorry. I was reviewing my answer and did that by mistake :)

Comment: @abatishchev, yes but you don't have exceptions in your case. If you had exceptions, you couldn't have converted Parse to TryParse without a change in behavior. And in the absence of exceptions it is not faster.

Answer (score 714, accepted):

Given an array you can use the [`Array.ConvertAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.Parse(s));
```

Thanks to Marc Gravell for pointing out that the lambda can be omitted, yielding a shorter version shown below:

```
int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse);
```

A LINQ solution is similar, except you would need the extra `ToArray` call to get an array:

```
int[] myInts = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that one. +1

Comment: The IL code this generates is actually less than Simon Fox's answer, FWIW

Comment: Actually, you don't need the lambda; `ConvertAll(arr, int.Parse)` is sufficient

Comment: Lambda is needed in VB.Net 2010: uArray = Array.ConvertAll(sNums.Split(","), Function(i) UInteger.Parse(i))

Comment: I did this to convert an `int[]` array to an `String` array: `Array.ConvertAll(chaptersIds, Convert.ToString)` Pretty nice! :D

Comment: @BSalita No, in VB.Net it's `Array.ConvertAll(arr, AddressOf Integer.Parse)`

Comment: you don't check for errors, it is not a good practice to assume that all strings are well formatted even if you think so, many things can go wrong and you end up with an exception that there is an un-parsable string

Comment: @AmrAlaa congrats, you're the first downvoter :) Seriously though, the original question shows an approach using TryParse, so if anyone wants to check for errors that's one option, with some drawbacks. I don't disagree with you; error checking is important, but I feel the answer was sufficient for the question and did not get exhaustive about error checking. StackOverflow should point you to a solution, but that doesn't mean it should be copy-pasted into our projects without reflection and enhancements as needed.

Answer (score 36):

EDIT: to convert to array

```
int[] asIntegers = arr.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

This should do the trick:

```
var asIntegers = arr.Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

Comment: .ToArray() required to satisfy OP's question

Comment: change var to int[] and append .ToArray() if you need it as an int array

Answer (score 30):

To avoid exceptions with `.Parse`, here are some `.TryParse` alternatives.

To use only the elements that can be parsed:

```
string[] arr = { null, " ", " 1 ", " 002 ", "3.0" };
int i = 0; 
var a = (from s in arr where int.TryParse(s, out i) select i).ToArray();  // a = { 1, 2 }
```

or

```
var a = arr.SelectMany(s => int.TryParse(s, out i) ? new[] { i } : new int[0]).ToArray();
```

---

Alternatives using `0` for the elements that can't be parsed:

```
int i; 
var a = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : 0); //a = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 0 }
```

or

```
var a = arr.Select((s, i) => int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : 0).ToArray();
```

[C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7):

```
var a = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.TryParse(s, out var i) ? i : 0);
```

Comment: The second solution: `var a = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).Where(i => int.TryParse(arr[i], out i)).ToArray();` just returns the indeces 0,1,2,... instead of the real values. What's the right solution here?

Comment: Thanks @Beetee. Not sure what I was thinking with that. I replaced it with another alternative.

Comment: @Slai: Thanks. But what does `new int[0]`? When I have text, I don't get a `0` in my array...

Comment: @Beetee `new int[0]` is an empty int array. The first two examples skip values that can't be parsed, and the last two examples use `0` for values that can't be parsed.

Comment: @Slai: Ah now I get it. I mixed it up with `new int[] {0}`. Thx.

Comment: if you're using VB.net, the query syntax won't work. You'll need to use the method syntax. arr.Where(Function(s) Integer.TryParse(s, i)).Select(Function(s) i).ToList()

Comment: @anphu where might not be needed in VB as it has the safe [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.val) function `(From s In arr Select Int(Val(s))).ToArray`, with optional `Where isnumeric(s)` if needed

Answer (score 14):

you can simply cast a string array to int array  by:

```
var converted = arr.Select(int.Parse)
```

Comment: nice!  thankyou.  And in VB.Net `Dim converted = arr.Select(addressof Integer.Parse)`

Answer (score 4):

```
var asIntegers = arr.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Have to make sure you are not getting an `IEnumerable<int>` as a return

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = arr.Select(i => Int32.Parse(i));
```