# Find the first free id

Tags: c#, sql, linq

One of my small database management projects (written in delphi) used sql queries to find the first free id of mysql table.

Example: I have to find the first free id (hole) in a table like this:

```
| id   | Col1 |
|------|------|
| 5101 | ABC  |
| 5102 | BCD  |
| 5103 | CDE  |
| 5105 | EFG  |  first missing id
| 5106 | GHI  |
| 5108 | ILM  |
```

The code should find the first free id `5104`

Here's how I'd do it in SQL (in old project):

```sql
SELECT
  MIN((doc.id + 1)) AS nextID
FROM (doc
  LEFT JOIN doc doc1
    ON (((doc.id + 1) = doc1.id)))
WHERE (ISNULL(doc1.id) AND (doc.id > 5000))
```

Now, which I am rewriting in c # language, I need to convert sql statements into a LINQ query (which uses Devart dotConnect for mysql Entity Framework).
Starting from here:

```
DC db = new DC();
var nums = db.Documentos.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: But you need it to add a row with such value? or for other purpose?

Comment: I have to fill in the empty rows

Comment: If you are using DB generated Ids simply add results till the desired ID

Comment: This smells like an X/Y question. Normally database IDs are not reused. It will be allmost impossible to make this concurrency-safe. Is your Db single use only?

Comment: the database is multi-user, but I use it only for extraordinary activity

Comment: Which type of LINQ are you using? As you see in the answers, people easily assume you can do this all in memory but I'm pretty sure you want the database to do the heavy lifting as it did with the SQL statement.

Comment: @Gert Arnold must do the datatbase work, using System.Linq

Comment: OK, but as said above, it's unusual, and not recommended, to reuse database IDs. Why do holes in the ID range matter?

Comment: @Gert Arnold a maintenance application must find the missing ids (deleted ?)

Comment: Well, still doesn't explain why. Anyway, I would create a scalar-valued database function that returns the available ID. Faster than LINQ and therefore less sensitive to concurrency. But never forget that database IDs (surrogate keys) with meaning to the business domain is a major architectural flaw.

Answer (score 0):

From [Can LINQ be used to find gaps in a sorted list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270321/1366033):

```
var strings = new string[] { "7", "13", "8", "12", "10", "11", "14" };
var list = strings.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s));
var result = Enumerable.Range(list.Min(), list.Count).Except(list).First(); // 9
```

Basically, order the list.  Then create an array of sequential numbers (`1,2,3...`) from the minimum all the way to the max.  Check for missing values in the list, and grab the first one.  That's the first missing number.

Answer (score 0):

This can give you all gaps within your table

```
var nums= (new List<int> (){1,2,3,25,4,5,6,7,8, 12, 15,21,22,23}).AsQueryable();

nums
  .OrderBy(x => x)
  .GroupJoin(nums, n=> n + 1, ni => ni, (o,i)=> new {o, i})
  .Where(t=> !(t.i is IGrouping<int, int>))
  .Dump();
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rJphil)

Comment: please check my answer again. I have added .Net Fiddle link

Comment: what is the exact error? can you post exact error? and instead of editing my answer please edit your question and add your attempt there

Answer (score 0):

Another method (similar to what you're using now).
Assume you have an array of integers (or another type of collection) like this:

```
var myIDs = new int[] { 5101, 5113, 5102, 5103, 5110, 5104, 5105, 5116, 5106, 5107, 5108, 5112, 5114, 5115 };
```

If it's not already ordered, the `OrderBy()` it:

```
myIDs = myIDs.OrderBy(n => n).ToArray();
```

Extract the first number that is less than `(next number) + 1`:

```
int result = myIDs.Where((n, i) => (i < myIDs.Length - 1) && (n + 1 < myIDs[i + 1])).FirstOrDefault();
```

If none of the members of this collection satisfy the condition, take the last one and add `1`:

```
result = result == default ? myIDs.Last() + 1 : result;
```

Comment: OP is using dbContext. This approach means that he need to load everything in memory and then execute it. This does not work for big data

Comment: @Simonare  Are you sure? I don't see where this is described. I just saw *convert to C# LINQ expression*.

Comment: I double checked it and It seems that I presumed it because of SQL. sorry about that :)

Comment: @Simonare Well, it might be as you say. The context is not that clear.  Maybe, the OP will define it better seeing these comments.

Comment: @Jimi I followed your advice and explained it better (I hope)