# How to convert a String[] to int[] in C# and .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I've got :

```
string[] strArray = new string[3] { "1", "2", "12" };
```

And I want something like this

```
int[] intArray = Convert.toIntArray(strArray);
```

I work int C# .net v2.0, I don't want to write a lot of code.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: .Net 3.0+ version for people from google: `int[] intArr = strArr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: (embarassing comment removed)

Comment: @Callum: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-string-of-code-using-linq ;) P.S. Your code isn't the best you can get for the task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string\[\] to int\[\] in one line of code using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the [**`Array.ConvertAll`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method for this purpose, which "converts an array of one type to an array of another type."

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(strArray,
                                  delegate(string s) { return int.Parse(s); });
```

(EDIT: Type-inference works fine with this technique. Alternatively, you could also use an implicit method-group conversion as in Marc Gravell's answer, but you would have to specify the generic type-arguments explicitly.)

Using a for-loop:

```
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
   intArray[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
```

For completeness, the idiomatic way of doing this in C# 4.0 would be something like:

```
var intArray = strArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

or:

```
//EDIT: Probably faster since a fixed-size buffer is used
var intArray = Array.ConvertAll(strArray, int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 19):

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(strArray, int.Parse);
```

or in C# 2.0 (where the generic type inference is weaker):

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll<string,int>(strArray, int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

int Convert(string s)
{
    return Int32.Parse(s);
}

int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(input, new Converter<string, int>(Convert));
```

or

```
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(input, delegate(string s) { return Int32.Parse(s); })
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.ConvertAll Generic Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Converts an array of one type to an array of another type.

Answer (score 1):

When you are sure, all items are definitely parsable, this will do the trick:

```
string[] strArray = new string[3] { "1", "2", "12" };
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
{
    intArray[i] = int.Parse(strArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but you want to keep a bit of error checking ( my if is really lame, just as example ):

```
static private int[] toIntArray(string[] strArray)
{
    int[] intArray = new int[strArray.Length];
    for (int index = 0; index < strArray.Length; index++)
    {
            intArray[index] = Int32.Parse(strArray[index]);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
string[] strArray = new string[3] { "1", "2", "12" };
int[] interi = toIntArray(strArray);
```

Comment: Int32.Parse can't return null - it returns an int.

Comment: `Int32.Parse()` returns `Int32` that is struct (value type), thus `!= null` always passes. This line of code generates a warning concerning what am I talking about.