# Converting Array Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string[] to int[] in one string of code using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-string-of-code-using-linq)

I have an array of strings I want to convert it to array of int

is there any way to convert it directly without looping

I mean without use foreach, for , LINQ select statement, etc.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: And what is the relation between the string in the array and the int to which it converts?

Comment: @abatishchev: No, it's not. AMH tries to do it without LINQ.

Comment: "without use foreach, for , LINQ select statement, etc" - that doesn't leave a whole lot. Why such a silly constraint?

Comment: it's not a silly constraint , it's due to performance issue , we need to enhance the performance I tried the foreach but it's so slow

Comment: Trying to improve performance by arbitrarily striking options... good plan.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Array.ConvertAll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx

Comment: I had no idea pretty cool method

Comment: @james Deville may ask about the performace is it faster , than looping

Comment: @AMH - not sure unfortunately. I would hope that it is optimized, but i don't know for certain

Comment: This function will loop though every instance just as yours would.  There is no way to act on every item with out performing the iteration.

Comment: for ur information , it increased the performance incredibly , what was taken  hours now take just few seconds, thanks a lot

Comment: @rerun if you were to modify the metadata (type pointed to and size of each element), then you could convert the array in O(1) time, couldn't you?