# How to convert string system collection to int?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, charts

I have a windows form chart that retrieve the x value in mysql database and plot it on a bar graph. This is the the first time I'm doing this so I don't really have an idea why I am getting this error.

```
public void loadChart()
    {
        string conn = "server=localhost;user=root;password='';database=cashieringdb;";
        string cmdstring = "SELECT sum FROM salessum";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.SeaGreen;
        this.chart1.Titles.Add("Daily Record");
        int[] pointsArray = a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum"); // error in this line
        string[] seriesArray = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Th", "Fri" };

        for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Series series =this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);
            series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
        }
```

Here's the error shows: No matter how much time searching for solution on the internet, but still I ca'nt get this working. Or is there any easy way to retrieve data from database and plot it on the windows form chart?

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>[]' to 'int[]'
```

**EDIT**

I change my code to this:

```
 List<string>[] pointsArray = a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum"); //no error
```

Error in this line:

```
 series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
```

Comment: Where u are getting this exception in code

Comment: look at the code I post thre is a comment line there

Comment: Well, what *is* `a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum")` really? Because as the error suggests, it clearly isn't an `int[]`. Try `var obj = a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum");` and see of what type `obj` is. And maybe you can find a way to get an `int[]` from whatever `obj` is.

Comment: Does `chart1.Series.Add(...)` take a `string[]` ? shouldn't it be a collection of points/koordinates in the chart?

Comment: @Corak yes it is a string

Comment: @Jens Kloster the value from database is a varchar not an int but I thought that varcahr holds both string and int values isn't it?

Comment: Yes it can hold both string and int value but int [] can't in c#

Comment: @user2262382 well there you have it. There is no implicit cast from `string` to `int[]` so you have to make one yourself.

Comment: a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum") returns List<string> or List<string>[]  ?

Comment: but all of my values from my database column sum is just pure numbers and never be inputed a letters. can I just change its type to int?

Comment: @RajeevKumar - Varchar can hold int?  As an integer?  Are you sure about that?

Comment: If you only ever store `int`s in that field of your table then yes, by all means change that fieldtype to `INTEGER`.

Comment: I will try changing it and I will let you know if that will work.

Comment: Btw. if `salessum` is any indication, you will probably want to work with numbers with decimal places (if not now, than maybe at some point in the future). So you might want to consider using `DECIMAL`. (For financial stuff, stay far away from `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are converting a List to int[]. You can not implicitly do this, you have to do this explicitly. you can do this easily using `Linq`.

I assume that `a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum");` is a method call. and out put a list of strings(**each string representing a number**)

Something Like this:

```
int[] pointsArray = a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum").Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToArray();
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-string-of-code-using-linq) will be helpful to you as well.

Edited:
Take a look at the LINK I have added earlier and get an idea on what you are going to accomplish. :)

in this code,

```
series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
```

`Points.Add` method do not expect a string it expects a `int`. What you have tried to do earlier is correct. So point Array has to be a `int[]`.
I mean this code:

```
int[] pointsArray = a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum");
```

I think I have found the exact same thing that you want to accomplish. Please take a look at this [**LINK**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/chart). This will be helpful to you.

Comment: if you look at the error message ' a.mysqlSelect("select sum from salessum") ' is a List<string>[] not a List<string>  so your code won't work.

Comment: Hi I try your code but I have an error in this line `int.Parse(i))`

Comment: no it is different and I'm browsing your given link, thanks to that anyway.

Comment: @Diode yes at the link you post that is what exactly I am trying to do the difference is just the values from pintsArray are retrieve from database which is I am now trying to fix.

Comment: @Diode please see this http://i495.photobucket.com/albums/rr312/flame25dragon/Untitled_zpsac8bb86e.png   I am the one who made this question I already have an output but only show different result.