# How to convert string array to int array to make calculation?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I want to read the integers after the /. thats why i tried to use this code:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] ip = line.Split('/');
    Console.WriteLine(ip[1]);                    
}
```

this code returns me this integers as string. I want to some math calculation with this numbers ,for example, multiplication. I tried this code but it doesnt work

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(ip, int.Parse);
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: I think one of items in `ip` array cannot be parsed as integer

Comment: If you try to convert ip-adresses, this wont work that simple.

Comment: output of the ip[1]=24,25,26,27

Comment: You need to split up the ip itself since it is made up from 4 Int values, seperated by a dot

Comment: may i not convert just ip[1]. i have to convert all ip values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert *each* item of `ip` array to integer. At lease second item of it - `"24 25 26 27"` cannot be converted to single integer value. You should take this item of `ip` array, split it by white space and then parse each part to integer:

```
int[] intArray = ip[1].Split().Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Or

```
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(ip[1].Split(), Int32.Parse);
```

Comment: im sorry its my mistake output just 24 25 26 27

Comment: @MehmetYüce by output you mean value of `ip[1]` item? Let me make question clear - you split line by `/`. That gives you `ip` array with second item having value like `24 25 26 27` and you want to convert this second item to array of integers?

Comment: @MehmetYüce OK, updated code - you should just use `Split()` without parameters or `Split(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

If its really about IP-Adresses, this might help

```
class IPV4Adress
{
      public int BlockA {get; set;}
      public int BlockB {get; set;}
      public int BlockC {get; set;}
      public int BlockD {get; set;}

      public IPV4Adress(string input)
      {
           If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                throw new ArgumentException(input);

           int[] parts = input.Split(new char{',', '.'}).Select(Int32.Pase).ToArray();
           BlockA = parts[0];
           BlockB = parts[1];
           BlockC = parts[2];
           BlockD = parts[3];
      }

      public override ToString()
      {
           return String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",BlockA, BlockB, BlockC, BlockD);
      }        
}
```

Then read it from File:

```
IPV4Adress[] adresses = File.ReadLines(fileName).SelectMany(line=>line.Split('/')).Select(part => new IPV4Adress(part)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I am bored and thought, why not provide a fullblown soloution.

Comment: ups, I didn't see the comments sorry I thought how is this related with ip adresses but apparently it is:)

Answer (score 0):

Given an array you can use the [`Array.ConvertAll` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.Parse(s));
```

**(or)**

```
int[] myInts = arr.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

**(Or)**

```
var converted = arr.Select(int.Parse)
```

A LINQ solution is similar, except you would need the extra `ToArray` call to get an array:

```
int[] myInts = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

[Sourec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-string-of-code-using-linq)