# Cast List<B> to List<A>

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want to to cast a list of object type A to a list of object type B, where A inherit B.

Concretely :

```
public class A : B
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public B() { }
}
```

I parse a JSON string that I cast to my list of type A :

```
B elem = ((JArray)_configuration).ToObject<List<A>>();
```

And I have this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< A>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List< B>'

I tried to cast it :

```
List<B> elem = (List<B>)((JArray)_configuration).ToObject<List<A>>();
```

but got this error :

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< A>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List< B>'

I couldn't find help, maybe because I don't know what to look for, so apologies if it has been answered somewhere already !

Comment: `(...).Cast<A>().ToList();` if you must

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/cast-listx-to-listy  The thing is you'll need to cast them individually, because [collections don't behave like you think they do](http://coding-time.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/covariance-and-contravariance-simple.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: Do you need the output to be a `List<A>`? If you just need to read from the list you can do `IReadOnlyList<A> l = inputList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Enumerable.Cast<>()` for this.

```
List<B> list = myList.Cast<B>().ToList();
```

But the `ToList()` will create a copy. If you just want for iterate the items. Don't use the `ToList()` and handle it as an `IEnumerable<B>`. It will be cast lazy 'on-the-fly'

Comment: Thanks, I think this solution is better than the one I've found

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found the answer if it can help. If not, tell me and I will remove the question. Sorry for that !

Just needed to do :

```
List<B> elem = new List<B>(((JArray)_configuration).ToObject<List<A>>());
```

Comment: There is no need to remove your question, instead, you should wait for couple of days and accept your own answer.

Comment: you can also do

List<B> elem=>(((JArray)_configuration).ToObject<List<A>>().Cast<B>().ToList()

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/convert-lista-to-listb-using-convertall-in-C-Sharp/), use list.selectall.

you can also try [this for arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq).