# Why do I need to initialize an out variable when using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Supposing I have a string which I want to convert to an integer, I would do

```
int i;
int.TryParse(someString, out i);
```

Now I would like to do the same in a Linq query:

```
int i;
var numbers =
   from s in someStrings
   where int.TryParse(s, out i)
   select i;
```

But this refuses to compile with the error

> CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'i'

It compiles and works as intended when I initialize i to an arbitraty value. But why do I have to?

Comment: few alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq/37033140#37033140

Comment: This is great, because LINQ functions are not supposed to create side effects (i.e. change state outside their own method scope). C#, not being a strict functional programming language, can't enforce that, but at least this is one example where it happens to do so. To make this work tidily, you'll have to use an alternative that declares `i` in the delegate (for the `Where` method) itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query expression is translated into:

```
var numbers = someStrings.Where(s => int.TryParse(s, out i))
                         .Select(s => i);
```

Now, *we* know that the delegate created from the lambda expression for the `Where` call will be executed before the delegate created from the lambda expression for the `Select` call, but the compiler doesn't. And indeed, you could easily write your own extension method that didn't obey that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    // I can't be bothered to check the predicate... let's just return everything
    return source;
}
```

At that point, with the normal `Select` call, your delegate returning `i` would be executed without every assigning a value to it.

Basically, the definite assignment rules are deliberately quite conservative, avoiding making any assumptions about what methods do etc.

Comment: What would be the value of i if the Where selected no values ? I think thats what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @PhillipH: With normal LINQ, if the `Where` predicate always returned `false`, the `Select` projection would never be called - so that wouldn't be a problem. The problem is the opposite - that the compiler doesn't know that the `Where` predicate *will* always be called before `Select`.

Answer (score 2):

This compiles to a pair of lambda expressions that are passed to `Where()` and `Select()`.

The compiler does not know what `Where()` and `Select()` do, and cannot prove that `Where()`'s lambda will always run before `Select()`.

Comment: Or that Select will ever be run ?

Comment: @PhillipH: If Select never runs, there wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler cannot determine until runtime whether or not there will be any records returned. So in order for i to have a determined value, one must be explcitly assigned. Just think "what would i be if my Query returned no rows ?"

Comment: Then the sequence would be empty, and the `s => i` lambda expression would never be executed.

Comment: But .net cannot determine at compile time whether it ever will be executed, and this would lead to the select statement, which may be executed (as far as the compiler knows), operating on an undefined variable.

Comment: But that wouldn't be the case if the sequence is empty, that's my point - the situation you've suggested would be a case where it *wasn't* a problem, whereas it's more useful to show a case which *would* be a problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm not being clear, or am not understanding your point - either way a good thread. If someStrings is empty then the Where function never gets called. In this case "i" is undefined, so cannot be assigned in the Select. The compiler cannot tell whether or not someStrings will be empty, so sees "i" as potentially unassigned (since its assignation is dependent on some externality). Its the same as "float i; if(z == y) t = 5; float j = t;" The assignment of "t" is dependent, so is potentially undefined at the point of usage. A definite assignment is required.

Comment: If the delegate passed to `Where` never gets called, why would the delegate passed to `Select` get called? What would you expect its input to be? Again, you're focusing on a corner case which actually *wouldn't* be a problem. It's better to give examples where it *would*, as I tried to in my answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is or isnt called. This is not a runtime error - its a compile time error. The value of "i" cannot be said to be definitely assigned because its dependent on the number of items in someStrings - so correctly the compiler flags this.

Comment: No, the value of `i` cannot be said to be definitely assigned because that would require the compiler to know what `Where` did, and that the number of times the delegate was called depends on the number of items in `someStrings` - if it knew that much information, it could probably also know that if `someStrings` is empty than the *use* of `i` wouldn't be reachable anyway. The special case of `someStrings` being empty is simply a red herring here - I don't think it helps anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet - but thats why the compiler is protesting with a "CS0165" becuase the code is structued such that there is no definite execution of the Where code block. You marked down my answer; but it explains why the OP was getting the compiler error - because the code is written in such a way that it cannot determine whether the assignment ever gets executed. We seem to be agreeing with each other here - anyhow SO tells me we are out of comment thread space, :-)

Comment: Your answer talks about whether any records will be returned as the cause of the problem. That's *not* the cause of the problem - I don't believe anyone reading just your answer would understand the real issue.