# Convert a string in a List<int> using LINQ (cleaner way)

Tags: c#, linq, out, tryparse

I have this string:

```
string input = "1,2,3,4,s,6";
```

Pay attention to the `s` character.

I just want to convert this string in a `List<int>` using LINQ. I initially tried in this way:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
input.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(n =>
    myList.Add(int.TryParse(n, out int num) ? num : -1)
);
lista.RemoveAll(e => e == -1);
```

But I prefer not have any `-1` instead of a no-number characters.

So now I try with this:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
input.Split(',').ToList()
    .FindAll(n => int.TryParse(n, out int _))
    .ForEach(num => myList.Add(int.Parse(num)));
```

I prefer this, but is really a shame that the parsing happening two times (`TryParse` at first and then `Parse`). But, from what I understand, the out variable in TryParse is useless (or not?).

Have you others suggests (using LINQ)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq/37033140#37033140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ParsesStringsToIntsWithLinq
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Parse(string input)
    {
        var i = 0;
        return (from segment in input.Split(',')
            where int.TryParse(segment, out i) 
            select i);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IgnoresNonIntegers()
    {
        var input = "1,2,3,4,s,6";
        var output = new ParsesStringsToIntsWithLinq().Parse(input);
        Assert.IsTrue(output.SequenceEqual(new []{1,2,3,4,6}));
    }
}
```

It doesn't return a `List<int>` but I have to draw the line somewhere. You can make a list out of it.

Comment: could be a static method so you don't have to new a class

Comment: I like your solution. My variant is: `var a = input.Split(',').Where(str => int.TryParse(str, out number)).Select(_ => number);`

Answer (score 1):

Using a nice extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T source) {
    yield return source;
}
```

(which you can replace with `new[] { n }` if preferred)

```
input.Split(',').SelectMany(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out var n) ? n.AsSingleton()  : Enumerable.Empty<int>()).ToList()
```

Comment: That's a neat solution, don't really like the iterator tho.

Comment: You mean the `AsSingleton` ? As mentioned, you can replace it with `new[] { n }` instead.

Comment: This is a bad overload of the name `Singleton`. Surely there's a better name.

Comment: The LINQ method `Enumerable.Repeat(source, 1)` already does this.

Comment: interesting approach, reminded me of this [YOW! Nights October 2013 Joe Albahari - Programming With Purity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZCzG2I8Hds&t=26m9s) talk. Creating array is a tiny bit cheaper and faster than creating iterator `.SelectMany(s => int.TryParse(s, out var n) ? new[] { n } : new int[0])`

Comment: @Enigmativity The name is based on mathematics - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29566211/2557128

Comment: @slai Actually using a lot of code to create a custom iterator turns out to be faster than anything else because the compiler optimizes out of boxing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34038332/2557128. I do wonder if `new int[0]` is better than `Enumerable.Empty<int>()`.

Comment: Checking source looks like `Enumerable.Empty` should be much better than `new int[0]` since it returns a static array reference instead of creating a new object each time.

Comment: BTW, some (me included) do not like the semantics of `Repeat` once.

Comment: @NetMage - Do you mean "repeat once" would issue "two values"?

Comment: No, just that "repeat one times" seems like a peculiar grammatical construction, even in a programming language. It doesn't represent the intent of the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make a nice helper function:

```
Func<string, int?> tryParse = s => int.TryParse(s, out int n) ? (int?)n : null;
```

Then it's a simple matter to parse:

```
string input = "1,2,3,4,s,6";

List<int> myList =
    input
        .Split(',')
        .Select(s => tryParse(s))
        .Where(n => n.HasValue)
        .Select(n => n.Value)
        .ToList();
```

That gives:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0; 
var myList = (from s in input.Split(',') where int.TryParse(s, out i) select i).ToList();
```

---

If the numbers are always single ASCII digits:

```
var myList = "1,2,3,4,s,6".Select(c => c ^ 48).Where(i => i < 10).ToList();
```

---

Few slower RegEx alternatives for fun:

```
var myList2 = Regex.Split("1,2,3,4,s,6", "[^0-9]+").Select(int.Parse).ToList(); // if the string starts and ends with digits

var myList3 = Regex.Replace("1,2,3,4,s,6", "[^0-9]+", " ").Trim().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

var myList4 = Regex.Matches("1,2,3,4,s,6", "[0-9]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: No, are not digits only. But I like your first solution

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be LINQ?

Try:

```
//Come up a better name...
public static List<int> ConvertToIntListNoLinq(string input)
{
    List<int> output = new List<int>();
    foreach(string s in input.Split(','))
    {
        if(int.TryParse(s, out int result))
        {
            output.Add(result);
        }               
    }
    return output;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQPY1x)

Comment: The tests are hardly conclusive as with such low running times in the ms you have a large amount of jitter. To avoid this tests in general should run at least several seconds. If run your fiddle multiple times, I sometimes get that the LINQ version is 10x faster, which really shows the jitter with the way you set your test up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic LINQ extension, which utilizes a `delegate`. This will allow you to pass in a function returning a `bool`, while "retaining" the result of the `out` variable (like `int.TryParse`).

---

Usage:

```
string input = "1,2,3,4,s,6";
List<int> myList = input.Split(',').SelectTry<string, int>(int.TryParse).ToList();
```

---

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class LINQExtensions
{
    public delegate bool TryFunc<TSource, TResult>(TSource source, out TResult result);

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTry<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TryFunc<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        foreach (TSource item in source)
        {
            TResult result;
            if (selector(item, out result))
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a clean way too. Even though it uses that extra variable, the benefit we get is it is clean and understandable.

```
string ids = "2,4,2,4,5,s"
const int inValidInt = -99;
var ids = ids.Split(',')
.Select(id =>
{
    int parsedId = int.TryParse(id, out parsedId) ? parsedId : inValidInt;
    return parsedId;
})
.Where(x => x != inValidInt).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
List<int> numbers = input
    .Split(',')
    .Where(t => int.TryParse(t, out int a))
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What if there's a negative number?

Comment: @itsme86 The OP used negative numbers in their original code.

Comment: Good catch @itsme86. I will try to fix it.

Comment: @Dai My point is, `.Where(t => t.All(char.IsDigit))` will fail for negative numbers.

Comment: @itsme86 Looks like it cant be accomplished in a pretty manner using `All(char.IsDigit)`. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

- You don't need to call `.Split(...).ToList()` as `String[]` is already enumerable.
- You can use multiple statements in a lambda with braces.
- The `FindAll`, `ForEach` and `RemoveAll` methods are not Linq methods, they're members of `List<T>`. Their Linq equivalent is `Where`.

Like so:

```
List<Int32> numbers = "1,2,3,4,s,6"
    .Split(',')
    .Select( s => { Int32 val; return Int32.TryParse( s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out val ) ? val : -1 } )
    .Where( n => n != -1 )
    .ToList();
```

You can make it more concise with a helper method:

```
static Int32 Parse(String s) {
    Int32 ret;
    if( Int32.TryParse( s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ret ) ) {
        return ret;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Becomes:

```
List<Int32> numbers = "1,2,3,4,s,6"
    .Split(',')
    .Select( s => Parse( s ) )
    .Where( n => n != -1 )
    .ToList();
```

If you don't want to reserve `-1` then you can use nullable ints:

```
static Int32? Parse(String s) {
    Int32 ret;
    if( Int32.TryParse( s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ret ) ) {
        return ret;
    }
    return null;
}

List<Int32> numbers = "1,2,3,4,s,6"
    .Split(',')                     // String to String[]
    .Select( s => Parse( s ) )      // String[] to IEnumerable<Int32?>
    .Where( n => n != null )        // filter out nulls
    .Select( n => n.Value )         // IEnumerable<Int32?> to IEnumerable<Int32>
    .ToList();                      // IEnumerable<Int32> to List<Int32>
```

Comment: What happens if `-1` is in the list?

Comment: @NetMage The OP used -1 in their example.

Comment: Would be better to use `Nullable`.

Comment: @kiziu I have amended my answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please don't downvote without a constructive comment.

Comment: The constructive comment is there and upvoted - the nullable int edit is a good alternative

Comment: If you are going to have `Parse` return `Int32?` then you should have your where be `.Where(n => n.HasValue)`. BTW, you left out a close paren in the `if` in `Parse`. I would suggest `static Int32? Parse(String s) => Int32.TryParse( s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var ret ) ? (int?)ret : null;`

Comment: @NetMage `n => n != null` is completely equivalent to `n => n.HasValue`. Thank you for pointing out the missing paren, I've fixed that now.

Comment: No, it is still missing: `out ret ) {`.

Comment: @NetMage Sorry, fixed. I only saw the first.