# Type cannot be inferred within a generic delegate

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44681416), I wrote a LINQ extension that utilizes the following `delegate`, so I can pass in a function with an `out` variable, such as `int.TryParse`:

```
public delegate bool TryFunc<TSource, TResult>(TSource source, out TResult result);

public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTry<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TryFunc<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        TResult result;
        if (selector(item, out result))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use this extension, I have to explicitly specify the `<string, int>` types like so:

```
"1,2,3,4,s,6".Split(',').SelectTry<string, int>(int.TryParse); // [1,2,3,4,6]
```

---

I want to remove `<string, int>`, similar to how we can call `.Select(int.Parse)` without specifying `<int>`, but when I do, I get the following error:

> The type arguments for method 'LINQExtensions.SelectTry(IEnumerable, LINQExtensions.TryFunc)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

---

My question is, why can't the types be inferred? My understanding is that the compiler should know the signatures of `int.TryParse` and subsequently the `TryFunc` `delegate` at compile time.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015283/why-cant-c-sharp-compiler-infer-generic-type-delegate-from-function-signature help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be inferred because only one of those arguments fits and that's the string. The 2nd parameter is the `out int` and that cannot be specified in the generic arguments which is why it is saying the arguments cannot be inferred.

The only way to call `SelectTry` without specifying arguments is by declaring your delegate somewhere that points to `int.TryParse` and then passing it in as your parameter.

I know this isn't what you want, this is the only way I know of getting around specifying the arguments.

```
TryFunc<string, int> foo = int.TryParse;
var s = "1,2,3,4,s,6".Split(',').SelectTry(foo);
```

Remember, in order to pass in methods as delegates, the parameters must match 1:1. `int.TryParse` matches `TryFunc`, but it does not match `SelectTry`