# Error when converting splitted string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string that I take from a property of an object. I split IT into a list of strings that I then want to cast into a list of ints.

This is what the code looks like:

```
TheListOfInts = s.TheListOfStrings
  .Split(',')
  .ToList()
  .Select(g => Convert.ToInt32(g))
  .ToList();
```

I'm getting an error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

The problem is that sometimes `TheListOfStrings` is ;null; and I think that's what triggers the error. What can I add in the lambda to take into account the possibility of a null string?

Comment: Read the error message.  That has nothing to do with `null`.  Look at what your string actually contains.

Comment: Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We can only guess what the strings look like and thus what the actual problem is. My guesses would be that you either have empty strings in there, or spaces before/after the numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq/37033140#37033140

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing a string to an int you want to use `int.TryParse` to make sure it won't throw an exception. In linq you can do it this way:

```
var result = s.TheListOfStrings.Split(',')
              .Select(i => (int.TryParse(i, out var value), value))
              .Where(pair => pair.Item1) // remove items that failed to be parsed
              .Select(pair => pair.value) // take the parsed value
              .ToList();
```

This fixes the cases of the empty items from the split (you can still add the `RemoveEmptyEntries` flag) and also, in case an item is not a valid integer it won't parse it.

*Notice that the first `ToList()` that you added is not needed.*

---

As you are using a pre C# 7.0 version then you should:

```
int value;
var result = s.TheListOfStrings.Split(',')
              .Select(i => new { Succeeded = int.TryParse(i, out value), Value = value })
              .Where(pair => pair.Succeeded) // remove items that failed to be parsed
              .Select(pair => pair.Value) // take the parsed value
              .ToList();
```

Difference:

- Anonymous type instead of [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples)
- out instead of [`out var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables)

---

In your question you stated: *The problem is that sometimes `TheListOfStrings` is null and I think that's what triggers the error*.

This will not be the cause for the error as if it was you would have received a `NullReferenceException`.

To cope with that you can:

1. Use the `?.` operator (and then the result might be `null` instead of an empty collection.
2. Check if it is `null`:

   ```
   var result = s.TheListOfStrings == null ? 
                    Enumerable.Empty<int> () : 
                    /*The linq query above*/;
   ```

Comment: Looks like value it doesn't like the first .Select statement; var value

Comment: @frenchie What C# version are you using?

Comment: @KevinCook - If you look at the edit time that it was added it is before your comment :) And besides as OP didn't say in which environment we should strive to use the latest versions

Comment: Ok, looks good. In the meantime, I went another route but I'll accept the answer so it'll help others.

Comment: "Looking at the edit time" doesn't matter, since when I had refreshed, attempted to use your broken code, and then replied to what I was looking at on my screen, you had fixed it from the previous edit... :P  As far as using the latest and greatest, in most environments you'll find that companies don't upgrade instantly and making the code work for a greater number of users can be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
var TheListOfInts = s.TheListOfStrings.Split(',').Select(g => Int32.TryParse(g, out x) ? x : 0).ToList();
```

Use tryparse, and catch whether g is a valid integer and you can set a default if not. (I put the default to 0);

Comment: The first `ToList()` isn't needed and you can use `out int x` instead of declaring it separately. (I suspect the latter might depend on which version of C# is in use.)

Comment: he had it that way in his code, I just edited out the convert to a tryparse. *shrug*

Comment: It works properly as it is, hence my +1, but sometimes it is nice to add little improvements to an OP's code so that they can learn extra bits :)

Comment: Re: `out int x` - which version of VS are you using? I tried it in VS2017.

Comment: I'm running it in vs2015

Comment: My suspicion was correct - it was just added: [What’s New in C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) and the very first item mentioned is out variables.

Comment: How will OP be able to tell between a valid value of `0` and a case of a failed parse?

Comment: he can put a default of some number, -99 for instance...   I don't know his business rules...  He might need to keep the numbers in order and removed segments can mess things up as well...

Comment: The only thing I would say is that being these are integers, the OP should be retrieving an enumeration of `nullable<int>` and the default should be `null` as `0` *is* a valid integer.