# Read multiple lines and split on space c# console application

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have this user input:

first line: 1 2
second line: 0 1 1
third line: 1 0 0

with the code below I have managed to read all lines and store them into a list,
in the last bit of code what I want to do is to store the values like integer types Int32, can anyone tell me of a better way to do this operation?

```
 List<string> lines = new List<string>();
 string line;
 int count = -2;
 int totCount = 0;
 while (count<=totCount)
       {
          line = Console.ReadLine();

          lines.Add(line);
          count++;               
       }


 var line1 = lines[0];
 var line2 = lines[1];
 var line3 = lines[2];

 string[] ee = line1.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 int c = Int32.Parse(ee[1]);
 ...
```

Comment: what is your expected output? we cannot recommend a useful data structure unless we know what you intend to achieve. you could store them in an array, in a `List<int>`, ... if `trainInfo` is line1+line2+line3, you should show that because the current code does not compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq/37033140#37033140

Comment: my bad, it should say line1 and not traininfo, sry! the output is the digits that are entered by the user to be stored into integer types

Comment: and would you expect one item per line, with the integers of that line inside (as in @Dmitry's answer), or just a contiguous list of numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood you right and you want to input a collection `List<int[]>`, let's *extract a method*:

```
 private static IEnumerable<int[]> ReadData() {
   while (true) {
     Console.WriteLine("Next line of integers or q for quit");
     string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

     if (input == "q")
       break;

     yield return input
       .Split(new char[] {' ', '\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Select(item => int.Parse(item)) // int.TryParse will be better
       .ToArray();
   }
 }
```

Then you can put

```
 List<int[]> trainInfo = ReadData().ToList();
```

Comment: this seems like the answer that I'm looking for, I will test it out. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
public struct Data
{
    public Data(int intValue)
    {
        IntData = intValue;
    }

    public int IntData { get; private set; }  
}

var list = new List<Data>();
list.Add(new Data(123));
```

Comment: how is this preferable over List<int>?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.