# String Array to Int the If else Statement C#

Tags: c#, winforms

can you please help me. i have a problem with my code. i have string array and i want to convert in int then apply an if else condition.

> Military Time

```
string[] FlaggingTime = ((Hashtable)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("Time"))["FlaggingTime"].ToString().Trim().Split(new char[] { ',' });
string FlaggingTimeBuffer = ((Hashtable)ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("Time"))["FlaggingTimeBuffer"].ToString();

if (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")) > Convert.ToInt32(FlaggingTime) && Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")) < (Convert.ToInt32(FlaggingTime) + Convert.ToInt32(FlaggingTimeBuffer)) )
{
    //Do Something
}
else
{
    //Do Something
}
```

**Configurable File**

```
<Time>
    <add key="FlaggingTime" value="0700,0900"/>
    <add key="FlaggingTimeBuffer" value="100"/>
</Time>
```

Comment: This link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq

Comment: please clarify more. Edit your question. Whether `buffer` is in seconds? whether the time is in 12 hr clock or in 24 hr clock?

Comment: Performing time and period of times comparisons can be tricky.  C# has some great ways to help with this. You should look at the `System.DateTime` and `System.TimeSpan` structs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string\[\] to int\[\] in one line of code using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq)

Comment: what is `0700`? is it `7Hr 0Min`?

Comment: @SushantYelpale, its a military timing so they denote timing in 4 digit format `0700` means `7:00AM`, `2000` means `08:00 PM`

Comment: i use military time 0700 = 07:00am

Comment: clarify a bit more, which flagging time you want to compare `0700` or `0900`?

Comment: i want to compare both. like if ```07:45am``` **true** when ```08:45am``` **false** and if the time is ```09:45am``` **true**. that's why i use array because of flexible time checking. the user can edit the **FlaggingTime** what they prefer. like the user edit the ```0900``` to ```1000``` or the user add a FlaggingTime ```0700,0900,1000``` . like that. Sorry for bad english and grammar.

Comment: @iMemew, FlaggingTime is an array, so you might want to use a forloop and put your If condition with it and then compare.
Ex Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm")) >Convert.ToInt32(FlaggingTime[0])

Comment: Instead of a bunch of `Convert.ToInt`s inside the condition, convert the various values into separate `int` variables, then check those in the condition. That makes reasoning and debugging easier. Plus as Clint said, you need to check every value in the array separately, so you need to loop over it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FlaggingTimeBuffer` is in seconds, Does this satisfy your need?

```
string[] time ={
    "0700",
    "0900"
};
string buffer = "100";

TimeSpan timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var FlaggingTimes = time.Select(e => TimeSpan.ParseExact(e, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();

if (timeOfDay > FlaggingTimes[0] && timeOfDay < FlaggingTimes[1].Add(new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt16(buffer), 0)))
{
    //  ............
}
else
{
    //  ............
}
```