# Parse/convert string array to int

Tags: c#

I want to make summations in certain columns, initially I found a referral as follows [image: picture1]

then because I use one string in one column then I change the array from int to string as follows

```
string[,] a = {     
                    {"name song 1", 2},  
                    {"name song 2", 5},  
                    {"name song 3", 8}  
               };
```

then I run but an error appears

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to` string'

I have tried this [Convert string[] to int[] in one line of code using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297231/convert-string-to-int-in-one-line-of-code-using-linq)

because I was just learning this language I couldn't implement it
please help me thanks

Comment: Array is homogeneous data structure means you can store same types of data in array, In your example you are trying to store int in string array

Comment: in your demo you can wrap your int numbers in " to make them a string sequence but then you always has to cast or convert it to int

Comment: You could use an array of value tuples `(string, int)[]`,  You can even name them `(string Name, int Value)[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to use dictionary in this case, but it might be handy for you to know as well that you can store values of different types using the `object` type. Later you'll have to do type conversion to use math operations

```
object[,] a = 
{
    {"name song 1", 2},
    {"name song 2", 5},
    {"name song 3", 8}
};

var sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(a[i, 1]);
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

If you are familiar with classes, you could reorganize your multi-dimensional array into single-dimensional, which makes code way more readable.

This approach is better than the previous one or the one that uses dictionary, since you'll have to modify less code when `Song` class extends into more properties

```
public class Song
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Song[] a =
        {
            new Song() { Name ="name song 1", Value = 2 },
            new Song() { Name ="name song 2", Value = 5 },
            new Song() { Name ="name song 3", Value = 8 },
        };

        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += a[i].Value;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, I will try to implement it into my program

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to store key-value pairs, this can be done using a Dictionary. Checkout the following example:

```
var scoreBySong = new Dictionary<string, int> {
  {"name song 1", 2},  
  {"name song 2", 5},  
  {"name song 3", 8}  
}
```